# Changing date not reflected in previous view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am reading some book and I stumbled this thing.
In my ViewController when a user clicks change date button following
code is called:

```
- (IBAction)changeDate:(id)sender {

    DateViewController *vc = [[DateViewController alloc] init];

    [vc setItem: item];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

`item` is a pointer to a custom class object, which has ivar of type `NSDate *`;

Now, inside `DateViewController` when user already picked new date and wants
to navigate to previous view, I have following code:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [datePicker date]);

    item.dateCreated = [datePicker date]; // get selected date
}
```

This code works and when user goes back from above code change is reflected
in `item` data structure and user can see new date. However, if I change above code, to following code, it doesn't work anymore, any clues why?

(This does **NOT** work):

```
- (IBAction)changeDate:(id)sender {

    DateViewController *vc = [[DateViewController alloc] init];

     vc.userDate = currentItem.dateCreated;

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

DateViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [datePicker date]);

    self.userDate = [datePicker date];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, `item` is a mutable instance, because you can change the date that it contains. In the second case you are supplying the `NSDate` itself, which is immutable.

So, in the first case, you pass a reference to `item` which can be edited and these edits are available later.

But, the second case doesn't edit the original date, it just stores the chosen date into a property on the view controller which is in the middle of being dismissed.

Generally it is better to make the communication clear, so the view controller would pass the chosen date back to the caller by delegation or provide a property (like in your second case) that can be queried once the selection is made. Your first option is effectively hiding the data exchange by sharing the instance `item` while the second view controller is on display.

---

Immutable means that the object itself (its contents) can not be changed. It does not prevent any reference to the object from being changed. If we use arrays (where there are mutable an immutable versions) to demonstrate:

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray array];
NSArray *b = a;
[b editSomething]; // illegal (not a true method name but just an example of something you might want to try)
b = nil; // just nils b, no affect on a at all
```

And

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSArray array];
NSMutableArray *b = a;
[b addObject:@"String"]; // edits a, because a and b are the same object
b = nil; // just nils b, no affect on a at all
```

The `NSArray` is like the situation where you just pass the `NSDate`. The `NSMutableArray` is like the situation where you pass `item` (because you can change the contents).

Comment: Yes, but `self.userDate` actually points to `currentItem.dateCreated;` - isn't it? (because of the assignment in the second -from last- code snippet).

Comment: It does point to the same object, but by setting the property on `self` you don't edit the original, you just change what the property is referencing.

Comment: Even if I change the line in the last code snippet to: `userDate = [datePicker date];` from `self.userDate = [datePicker date];` - currentItem's date is still not updated when user comes back to this view ...

Comment: That change would just be a different way of changing `self` (assuming that you synthesized it yourself, badly). The point really is the mutable container (`item`) with a variable inside it.

Comment: Wain I don't get exactly what you mean. I mean I understand NSArray is like the situation with NSDate, but still again, with NSDate, I am trying to change (via `self.userDate` though) the pointer where `currentItem.dateCreated;` is pointing, not the contents of the NSDate object itself. Do you understand what I mean? (This is like the `b=nil` situation in your case which is permitted).

Comment: Permitted yes, but doesn't do what you want it to do because it just changes the **local** reference, not the reference in the original object.

Comment: Wain but I am doing exactly same type of assignment with `item` in the first case, and it  changes the original object right - why is this the case then?

Comment: But at the end you do `item.dateCreated` not `item = ...`, this is the difference that matters, changing the content, not the reference.

Comment: I think I got the point. ALthough mutability is not the main point here. The main trick is that by doing `userDate=...` I was changing `userDate` to point to smth else, not the original value. note: if NSDate were mutable, maybe it would be possible to change the Object to which `userDate` was pointing to directly, e.g., userDate.Assign(smth). I will accept your answer together with the comments